# Linux: Presenting a larger-than-real file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, samba

Does anybody know if it's possible to have a small Linux filesystem with *apparently* limitless (or very big) free space?

We have a Samba server with lots of filesystems, all available from a small "root" filesystem that only contains symlinks to the real filesystems (we use wide links in samba). No data will ever be put on this "root", only symlinks.

The problem is that smb clients (windows/mac) check the size of the share ("root") and refuse to copy data there if the size appears to be insufficient, even if it's plenty of space in the real location (ie. where the symlink points).

AFAICS, Samba can't fake disk space, but perhaps some filesystem can? Has anybody any suggestions here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of Samba's global options to solve this problem, as discussed [here](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch08_06.html). This Web page explicitly states:

> This global option is used on systems that incorrectly determine the free space left on the disk. So far, the only confirmed system that needs this option set is Ultrix. There is no default value for this option, which means that Samba already knows how to compute the free disk space on its own and the results are considered reliable. You can override it as follows:

```
[global]
    dfree command = /usr/local/bin/dfree
```

> This option should point to a script that should return the total disk space in a block, and the number of available blocks. The Samba documentation recommends the following as a usable script:

```
#!/bin/sh
 df $1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2" "$4}'
```

Just make sure that the above script is modified to include all of your different filesystems, and that it returns the **combined** figures for the sum of all filesystems. Or alternatively, for the specific filesystem
which you wish to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

disks=()
disks+=('/dev/disk/by-label/usb_4tb_wd')
disks+=('/dev/mapper/centos-root')

# http://superuser.com/questions/965321/linux-presenting-a-larger-than-real-file-system
# Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
# /dev/sdb1      3845532688 2577688240 1072495968  71% /mnt/usb_4tb_wd
#                3845532688            1072495968
df_total=0
df_available=0

for disk in "${disks[@]}" ; do
  ((df_total     = df_total     + $(df $disk | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}') ))
  ((df_available = df_available + $(df $disk | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}') ))
done

echo "$df_total $df_available"

exit 0
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this script will help the OP

Comment: Fond this page "googling" with the same problem.
This is the script "/usr/local/bin/dfree" posted/mentioned in the first answer.
Modified as suggested to sum space of several drives.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers have this right, but it seems silly to have to explicitly list each file system you want to total. In your samba file global section include the dfree command. https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch08_06.html

```
[global]
    dfree command = /usr/local/bin/dfree
```

Where the dfree command is:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" = "." ] && dir="$(pwd)" || dir="$1"
df --output="target"| \
  grep -P "^\\Q${dir%/}\\E/." | \
  xargs -d '\n' \
     df --output="size" --output="avail" --total "$dir" | \
  tail -1
```

Just a brief explanation.  The first df command is just to find the names of the mounts.  We grep filter the list using a perl expression so our file name can contain periods and other special characters. That list is then send to the xargs command. So we can pass to your dfree command that does the totals the names correctly escaped as shell arguments.   The final tail command is so we only display the totals.

*Note: It is legal for a linux filename to have linefeeds and carriage returns in it.  But I did not attempt to support such filenames in this script.  This also may not count directories mounted with the --bind option*

In regards to the more general question, can you fake a larger filesystem than what you really have in Linux?   Of course.  One of the easiest is if you create a file system image in on ext4 filesystem via:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=myimage.img bs=4K count=10485760 status=progress
mkfs -t ext4 myimage.img
```

You now have a 10 GiB file system.   But if you check with du -sk you'll see it only uses a fraction of that space on disk, until you actually start to fill.

You can over commit further by using lvm's [Thin Provisioning](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/thinprovisioned_volumes).